# How do you calculate time complexity for a function that has function within?

Tags: algorithm, callback, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I'm not sure if it's suitable to ask such a basic question but I was just wondering how to calculate a function that has another function inside.

From my understanding of Big O notation, if there are only multiple non-nested for loop, then it's O(n), and depending on the number of nesting loops, it increases by n squared.

but how about a function like below when there's a helper function within a function along with while loop and for loop.

```
function solution(nums) {
  let container = [];
  let zero = 0;
  let one = 1;
  let two = 2;
  let answer = 0;

  function isPrime(n) {
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if (n % i === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  while (nums) {
    container.push(nums[zero] + nums[one] + nums[two]);
    two++;
    if (two === nums.length) (one++, two = one + 1);
    if (one === nums.length -1) (zero++, one = zero + 1, two = one + 1);
    if (zero === nums.length-2) break;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    if (isPrime(container[i]) === true) answer++;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

I've read few articles about it and I'm guessing the above function is O(n log n)? I'm sorry for asking this question. I'm a beginner and I don't have a community or anybody to ask. I've always heard this place is "the" place to get programming question answers.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The complexity can’t be less than ```O(N^3)```, because of the ```while``` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is `O(n^2)`.

The inner function's (`isPrime()`) complexity itself is `O(i)`, where `i` is its input.

Since `isPrime()` is called for each value in the container, and the container contains `O(n)` elements, after being filled up in previous loop, the total number of operations it is going to do is: `O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)`.

Now, `1 + 2 + .... + n` is [Sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), and itself is in `O(n^2)`, thus your solution() is `O(n^2)`.